# Populate huge array in C with scanf

Tags: c, arrays, input, scanf, populate

Suppose my program has to receive 2 inputs:
the first corresponds to the size of the array,
and the second input corresponds to the elements of the array, separated by a single white space.

i.e. (input):

- 4
- 1 2 3 4

So i have to populate an array of size n=4 with 1,2,3,4 as their elements.
Now, the way i usually do would be something like:

```
int *vector=malloc(n*sizeof(int));
for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
    scanf("%d", &vector[i]);
}
```

Which works fine for small values of n (like 1000). But when i do it for, say, n=1 million, or even something like 100.000, that doesn't works at all. It gets stuck in an infinite loop.
So, is there another way to populate the array using scanf (or fgets or any other function)?

Comment: Your i is an integer which has a max value of 32767

Comment: "*that doesn't works at all*" is not a problem statement. Fix that

Comment: By "stuck in an infinite loop" do you mean that the for loop goes beyond n? i.e. where is it stuck in a loop and can you expand on how do you know?

Comment: @Psioniax - what makes you think an integer has a max value of 32767??!?

Comment: Can you read all this input from a file?  If it is large number of values, user input will be tedious.

Comment: If using a `long` doesn't fix it, it would be helpful to see more of your code.

Comment: Should  input contain non-convertible text like `"x"` or 2 `"-"` in a row, `scanf()` will not convert the input to a number and the offending text remains in the stream for the next call

Comment: The problem is not calling `scanf()` many times.  1) Check if `vector!=NULL`  2) Check result `scanf() == 1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignoring the fact that the performance is not as good as it should, you are not considering the following:

In C and C++ you have these requirements

> ```
> signed char: -2^07+1 to +2^07-1
> short:       -2^15+1 to +2^15-1
> int:         -2^15+1 to +2^15-1
> long:        -2^31+1 to +2^31-1
> long long:   -2^63+1 to +2^63-1
> ```

that means:

your code

```
 for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
    scanf("%d", &vector[i]);
}
```

is actually working but if you set the **n**value really big, then it generates an overflow and you will get stacked in an infinite loop...

Comment: So, you are saying i should go for a long or unsigned int, instead of just int?

Comment: am saying that if you do a for loop between 0 and 1 million but your counter  holds only 1000 values, your loop is going infinite....

Comment: so the number of inputs you need to read must be appropriately passed to the data type...

Comment: Use **long** or **unsigned long** for both counter and array if any data > 32,000.